EF many to many relationship in Web Api using swagger
I have a problem when I'm trying to set the many-to-many relationship in EF Core, and catch the result in Swagger.
public class  Book
{
    [Key]
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string? BookName { get; set; }
}

public class  Publisher
{
    [Key]
    public int PublisherId { get; set; }
    public string? PublisherName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BookPublisher? BookPublishers { get; set; }
}

public class BookPublisher
{
    [Key]
    public int BookPublisherId { get; set; }
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public int PublisherId { get; set; }

    public Book? Book { get; set; }
}

In the DbContext, I have:
DbSet<Publisher>? Publishers { get; set; }
DbSet<BookPublisher>? BookPublishers { get; set; }
DbSet<Book>? Books { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Publisher>().ToTable("TAB_Publisher", "dbo");
    builder.Entity<BookPublisher>().ToTable("TAB_BookPublisher", "dbo");
    builder.Entity<Book>().ToTable("TAB_Book", "dbo");
}

public List<Publisher>? GetPublishers()
{
    if (Publishers != null)
        return Publishers
               .Include(s => s.BookPublishers).ThenInclude(s => s.Book)
               .ToList<Publisher>();
    else
        return null;
}

When I call my method GetPublishers in Swagger, I get exactly what I wanted:
[
  {
    "PublisherId": 1,
    "PublisherName": "Publisher1",
    "BookPublisher": [
      {
        "BookPublisherId": 1,
        "BookId": 1,
        "PublisherId": 1,
        "Book": {
          "BookId": 1,
          "BookName": "TEST1",
        }
      },
      {
        "BookPublisherId": 2,
        "BookId": 2,
        "PublisherId": 1,
        "Book": {
          "BookId": 2,
          "BookName": "TEST2",
        }
      },
    ]
  }
]

How can I get the same result with the book? A book can have several publishers. What kind of relation do I have to set up?
Here is my cdm
enter image description here

Could you clarify what you mean by "the same result"? Are you referring to filtering by book or having the root as the book? If you're asking for the query result, please provide the DTO class and update your question accordingly. I'm specifically asking about the DTO class because it's considered a bad practice to expose the EF model directly in the API.

my entrance is Publisher but i want the entrance from book now. I need a method for having the root for book. You have all the class that i use.

is it possible to stop de cascading circle to only one level ?

Search on SO for this frequent question, you probably have circular refernce during JSON serilization - that's why DTO is needed.

What kind of relation do I have to set up? -- Just as you query publishers you can query books. It's the same relationship accessed from the other end. As said, the circular reference question is notorious and well answered.

you are right i have a circular reference but its normal. I had to the poste my cdm model :

For querying, you want ICollection<BookPublisher? BookPublishers in Book as well, but then you get this circular ref issue when serializing. That's why it's always recommended to project to DTO classes for query output.
